# How to display on the blog page the posts corresponding to the selected language, using Polylang

Tags: blog-page, plugin-polylang

I use Polylang (free) to internationalize a customer site. I set a default language (= FR), I added a language switcher in my navbar (FR and US flags) and I set the Front and Blog pages for both languages.

1) The language switcher works well with the pages. If you go to the homepage (http://cecile-chancerel-bijoux.com/wp/), you have the default FR homepage. When you click the US flag, it redirects you to the US homepage.

2) It's also true for the blog page (displaying posts list). I have 2 different URLs for the FR and US blogs. You can switch between them with the langage switcher flags :

FR : http://cecile-chancerel-bijoux.com/wp/blog/

US : http://cecile-chancerel-bijoux.com/wp/blog-en/

The problem is they both display the FR AND the US posts. Obviously I already set the language for these 2 posts. Check the screenshot here : http://res.cloudinary.com/dbhsa0hgf/image/upload/v1522144114/blog_issue_with_polylang_x7ev8p.png

I want the US blog (/blog-en) to display only the posts in English and the FR blog (/blog) to display only the posts in French. How can I achieve this ?

**EDIT :**

I use Themify's Elegant theme, thus I modified this file : wp-admin/wp_content/themes/themify-elegant/index.php like this :

I updated following block :

```
<?php// Loop?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  <div id="loops-wrapper">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php if(is_search()): ?>
       // some logic //
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php else : ?>
  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing found.', 'themify' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

with a custom query

```
<?php// Loop?>
  <?php $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'lang'           => pll_current_language('slug'),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
  );?>
  <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

  <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <div id="loops-wrapper">
      <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php if(is_search()): ?>
         // some logic //
        <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
  <?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing found.', 'themify' ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

And it works ! I eventually have only the posts in french displayed on my french blog page, same for the english one. Thanks @Friss, this is all thanks to you !

Guillaume

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help a compatriot ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add the lang parameter to your loop arguments like so

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'lang'           => pll_current_language('slug'), //returns 'en' for example    
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
) );
```

**However this is not the better practice** because by doing that way we override the main query which is not wp friendly.
We should better do like this using the pre_get_post action hook, so in your functions.php file:

```
if(function_exists('pll_current_language')) // if polylang
{
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_language' );
    function include_language( $query ) 
    {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() ) { //add more condition here if needed
            $query->set( 'lang', pll_current_language('slug') );
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: YEEAAAH, it works with polylang function. My Edit is updated accordingly. I am so grateful for your patience and the time you spent to solve this question ! I suggest that we clean a bit the discussion. I will remove all my comments above. Maybe you can also change your answer so that it shows the actual solution. Thanks again, you ve made my day !

Comment: i did not understand, do i need both functions or just one? would you mind explaining? thank youuu

Comment: No, just one, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function include_languages($query) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('lang', '');
    }
}
if (function_exists('pll_current_language')) {
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_languages' ); 
}
```

Comment: That looks like the other answer except you're setting lang to empty. Why the change? Why predicate this on pll_current_language if you're not using it?